AWS API Gateway custom domain name with mapping and proxy route based on path
I just can't figure this out.
Essentially, I have a URL of /v1/account, I have created the custom domain and created a mapping, however, no matter what I try, I get a Forbidden error in API Gateway (unless I have a $default route which does catch it).
The plan is to have a single API Gateway for all my services and it's dished out to them by the path (i.e. v1/account would be the account lambda).
The paths just don't seem to work in Gateway. What am I doing wrong. I've tried adding the version to mapping path (and removing from the Gateway) and all kinds of variations of this.
Mappings:

Gateway:


I think the problem is that your routes start with the /v1 prefix, which is the stage. You would use that if you accessed the API via the generated endpoint URL. However, when you use a custom domain name, you map the path (empty in your case) already to a stage. So the route should be just /account.
But I agree it's not specified clearly in the documentation.
